# I would like to create table of contents in this github webpages site

Tags: github, github-pages, tableofcontents

I would like to create a table of contents on the left side of this GitHub pages site https://abenjamin09.github.io/Bellabeat-Capstone-1/.
Any help would be appreciated! The section in the table of contents would ideally look like this.

Introduction

- Characters and Products

Step 1 - Ask

- List item

Step 2 - Prepare

ETC ETC

How would I go about doing this??

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You could use a static generator like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), whose result:

- can be [published to GitHub pages](https://youngkin.github.io/post/createafreeblogsite/#publishing-content-to-github-pages)
- can include [TOC (Table of Content)](https://gohugo.io/content-management/toc/)

Example: [Algorithms - Graphs](https://www.takuzen.me/hugo-theme-cactus/posts/2020-05-01-algorithms-graphs/#topological-sort) ([source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monkeyWzr/hugo-theme-cactus/67d1c816c5eef9adb2f0e8a44a837d8ac1db5871/exampleSite/content/posts/2020-05-01-algorithms-graphs.md)) has a TOC on the right side, because of  [TOC CSS rules](https://github.com/monkeyWzr/hugo-theme-cactus/blob/67d1c816c5eef9adb2f0e8a44a837d8ac1db5871/assets/scss/partial/post/actions_mobile.scss#L89-L149=)